# Application to display information from database

Tags: joomla

I understand that this is a very broad question and could get flagged but I need inputs from experienced programmers and will ask it anyway. If there is another forum where I can post this question, please let me know.
Currently we manage all our application information in an Excel spreadsheet. At a high level it contains an app id, the server names that it is hosted on and the name of the environment. The Excel spreadsheet has become too large and I am looking to build a simple application for it.
Ideally, I would like to write this app on Windows as everyone uses Windows but dont know how to go about it in Windows. I then thought of using MySQL and PHP or Perl (CGI) to build this but thought of exploring something new. I read about Joomla and a few other CMS products which make it very easy to build websites but am not sure whether these allows me to pull information from a database.
I am seeking inputs on what would be a good way to way to build this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Joomla! CMS is a good choice and to pull data from database you may use webservice calls. So, you will able to create a CMS website using joomla and will able to pull data easily from database with the help of webservice.

You can get webservice support in joomla by installing component redCORE in joomla.

- Component: https://github.com/redCOMPONENT-COM/redCORE
- Wiki:  http://redcomponent-com.github.io/redCORE/?chapters/webservices/overview.md
- Other videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzJkC7f9fJE 
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NRT5jh3Ewc
- Joomla dev group discussion https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-cms/3OctbkIZlQw/5d_1MLrzbgYJ

You can also post questions in Joomla forum http://forum.joomla.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think Joomla is a great option to handle big loads of information. If you already know PHP and don't need to reinvent the wheel, it's cool. The way of handling data in Joomla is using Components. 
If you want to try, it would be as easy as installing a local copy of Joomla, building the field structure on [component-creator.com](http://component-creator.com) installing it and importing the data inside the component using phpmyadmin.